# Hacer scrolldown despues de que cuando la web se recarga mediante un click a un boton

Tags: php, javascript

```
#Yo utilize una funcion de javascript, pero pasa que cuando se entra por primera vez a la web, se# #hace el scrolldown hacia abajo en automatico y no quiero eso, quiero que cuando se de click al boton,# #despues de recargar la pagina, entonces haga el scroll down.#
#Solo necesito esa función o alguna manera para hacerlo.#
```

La web se recarga debido al php que traer imagenes de la base de datos, pero lo que quiero es que
cuando se recargue la web, se mantenga hay, o que simplemente cuando recargue debido al click del boton haga scroll down

Use esta funcion pero, pasa que cuando se recarga la web sin darle click al boton, se va hacia abajo.

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 indow.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);  });

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido bien tu pregunta.

Cuando una página se recarga se queda en la parte superior. Si la página hace scroll hacia abajo es porque hay en algún sitio, en tu caso en el .js, una función.

Si lo que quieres es que no haga ese scroll simplemente quita esa parte del código. Porque si haces que haga scroll hacia arriba después de hacer scroll hacia abajo la página va a "bailar" abajo-arriba cada vez que se recarge

Comment: no jaja, ya encontre unos videos referentes, pasa que el codigo qque refresca la pagina es php, entonces ese codigo php trabaja con una paginacion para traer imagenes desde la bd, pero implementare ajax para que solo se recargue esa zona.